# Removing password_digest from API json?

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm using Sinatra to make a simple little API. I have not been able to figure out a way to remove the 'password_digest' field from the JSON I'm outputting. Well, I know of a long way that I can do it, but I have a feeling there is a much simpler way.

```
get "/users/all" do
content_type :json
@users = User.all

response = @users.map do |user|
  user = user.to_h  
  user.delete("password_digest")
  user
end
response.to_json
```

end

All I'm trying to do is remove the password_digest field from the output. Is there a simple way to do this? I've tried searching with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. There is no code showing your attempt to to remove that field.
Also, please remove the image and replace it with text. "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)" explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get "/users/all" do
  content_type :json
  @users = User.all
  @users.to_json(except: [:password_digest])
end
```

You can also overide [`#as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) on the model to remove the attribute completely from serialization:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(**options)
    # this coerces the option into an array and merges the passed
    # values with defaults
    excluding = [options[:exclude]].flatten
                                   .compact
                                   .union([:password_digest])
    super(options.merge(exclude: excluding))
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a security benefit to overriding the as_json?

Comment: Yes, as you can't accidentally forget to exclude it  later.

Comment: Beware: the option is called :except, not :exclude. @max maybe you want to edit the answer above? (For me it says "Suggested edit queue is full")

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```rb
  get "/users/all" do
    content_type :json
    @users = User.all

    response = @users.map do |user|
      user = user.to_h  # If your data is already a hash, you don't need this line.
      user.delete(:password_digest) # <-- If your keys are symbolized
      user.delete("password_digest") # <-- If your keys are strings
      user
    end
    response.to_json
  end
```

Comment: This did something to my data, not exactly sure what though "{\"id\":3,\"username\":\"owner-demo\",\"password_digest\":\" etc.. this is kind of how i originally tried to do it and I couldnt quite pick out that field. I added a pic of the json structure. Array of hashes

Comment: Thats only removing the field name "password_digest" and not its value as well.

Comment: Look at my solution again.  I edited it  to say `user_data = user.to_h` instead of `user_data = user.to_json` that was my mistake.   If your data is already a hash, then you don't need that line, you can omit it.